# Android app with Google API works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I have an Android App that uses the Google API, displaying a map and some markers on this map.
When I run the app on an emulator, the app works as expected, but when downloaded on an actual Andorid Phone it crashes.

The phone runs on Android 2.3.3, and the Google API version 15.
I have put this line in the AndroidManifest.xml-file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

I have also signed the Google API key with the release keystore, and ensured that the same keystore was used when signing the application it self.

As mentioned, when run on an emulator the app works fine, BUT i do get this error when the app is starting (after instalation):

```
MainActivity  couldn't get connection factory client
```

And then there is a bunch of exeptions/warnings of this type:

```
System.err    IOExeption processing: 26
System.err    java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
```

I'm new to Android programming, so I would appreciate any help that would solve this problem.

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 0):

First check if appropriate permissions is set in AndroidManifest.xml.
Check if you have provided correct google map key. To create Key http://www.pocketvnc.com/blog/?page_id=511
Also try to generate new MAP key and use it instead of using the old one.

Answer (score -1):

For testing on real hardware you need to use a key different from the debug key. Following your post you are using a debug keystore.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/v1/?csw=1#getfingerprint

Read that paragraph on google.

Is important that the application is exported as a signed application with the same key used for the google api (and NOT the debug key).

For create a valid read that paragraph:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

and then use the same key to obtain the google maps api key.

Once you have the key for your application you can export a signed application by clicking with right button of your mouse on the project select Android Tools and then Export as a signed application package and follow the wizard (probably you can create a new key using that wizard).

hope that help.

Comment: Yes, you can run an application signed with the debug key on a real phone. You can't publish a debug signed app on the Android Market, that's the restriction. If you do make a private release key and sign it with that, then you need a different Google Maps API key which matches your release key.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned in the question: I have made a release keystore and used it to get a Google api key. I've used the same keystore to sign the application.